# detail in proof of the mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I am trying to prove the following result

> If $f$ is a continuous function on a closed interval $[a,b]$, then
> there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that,
> $$f(c)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm{d}x$$

I have worked out the following proof

Because $f$ is continuous on the interval, it reaches a minimum $m$, and a maximum $M$ so that we have
$$\begin{aligned} m&\leq f(x)\leq M \\ m(b-a)\leq  & \int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\leq M(b-a) \\  m\leq &\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\;\mathrm{d}x\leq M\end{aligned}$$
and the IVT guarantees the exxistence of $c$ as above.

How do I prove that $c \neq a\ \& \ c\neq b$?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: The intermediate value theorem already ensures $c \in (a,b)$, so there's nothing you need to further verify

Comment: @EeveeTrainer That's not true. Perhaps that you are thinking about the mean value theorem.

Comment: Pretty sure it is true, based on the Wikipedia article -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Theorem

Comment: Take $f\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x$ and $u=0\bigl(\in\bigl[f(0),f(1)\bigr]\bigr)$. Are you claiming that there is some $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f(c)=u=0$?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer The statement you made is not true

Comment: Consider what happens when $m\ne M$.

Comment: Then, you can make your integral inequalities strict, and then use the IVT version mentioned by Eevee.

Comment: do you know where this theorem is from ? I have never seen this version, moreover, what if c=m and $m\neq M$

Comment: The IVT? If $d$ is strictly between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then of course the "$c$" given by whatever IVT you are using must be in $(a,b)$.

Comment: yes but $a\leq b \leq c$ and $a<c$, why does $a<b<c$, this is not true !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117581/discussion-between-t-d-and-david-mitra). @DavidMitra

Comment: I am not able to understand your objection to using FTC to prove this. In particular FTC does not require this result for its proof. The first part (crudely derivative of integral equals integrand) is derived just using definitions. The second part of FTC requires mean value theorem of derivatives.

Comment: well, the french education system excludes every proof using sums, as the integral is not defined rigourously. Students know and use the IVT and the bounds for continuous function thm regularly, Therefore I find it only appropriate to give them a proof of FTC. The assumption on this chapter is that continuous fct is integrable, linearity, and adjacent interval property (int over [a;b]= int over [a;c] + int over [b;c]). So the plan is using this to prove the MVT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is constant, there is nothing to do.

Otherwise, let $M=\max f$ and $m=\min f$ on $[a,b]$ with $m\neq M.$ Then, $m\le \frac{\int_a^bf(t)dt}{b-a}\le M$ so the Intermediate Value Theorem gives us a $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=\frac{\int_a^bf(t)dt}{b-a}.$

If $c\in (a,b),$ we are done.

If $c=a$ then $f(a)=\frac{\int_a^bf(t)dt}{b-a}.$ If $f(a)=m,$ then $\int_a^b(f(t)-m)dt=0$ and since $f-m\ge 0$ on $[a,b]$ and continuous there, $f-m=0$ and $f$ is constant. Similarly, if $f(a)=M$ we get $f=M$.

So there are $a<x_0\neq x_1<b$ such that $f(x_0)=m$ and $f(x_1)=M.$ Without loss of generality, $x_0<x_1.$

Then, $m<f(a)<M$ so appying the IVT again, we get a $x_0\le d\le x_1$ such that $f(d)=f(a)$ and the result follows.

An almost identical argument shows that the result also holds if $c=b.$

Comment: Many elementary calculus texts prove the MVT for integrals, then use that result to prove the FTC (e.g. the widely used *Tomas' Calculus*).  Thus your proof becomes circular.

Comment: Well, can't we just do this? Let $M_h=\max f$ on $[x,x+h]$ and $m_h=\min f$ on $[x,x+h]$. Then, $\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\frac{\int_x^{x+h}fdt}{h}$ and since $\frac{m_hh}{h}\le \frac{\int_x^{x+h}fdt}{h}\le \frac{M_hh}{h}$ we have $m_h-f(x)\le \frac{\int_x^{x+h}fdt}{h}-f(x)\le M_h-f(x).$ Let $h\to 0$ and use continuity of $f$ to get $F'(x)=f(x).$ No MVT for integrals.

Comment: I did not say that there wasn't a way of using your argument, only pointing out that your argument doesn't work in many contexts because of the way in which the exposition is structured.  Indeed, the asker dismissed another answer because of this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3958672/468350https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3958672/468350.

Comment: Fair enough. I will provide a "from scratch" proof and delete my comments.

Comment: @Matematleta the proof in comments is fine, and it uses the MVT to get to the inequalities with $m$ and $M$, right ?

Comment: The proof in my comment uses only properties of the integral and continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $w<z, w,z\in [a,b]$ with $f(w) = m, f(z) = M$

If $m=M \implies f$ is a constant function then all $c\in(a,b)$ works.

Suppose $m<M$

We have that for $c\in [w,z]$, $f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$

Suppose $c = a$, then $a = w$, because $a\leq w \leq c \leq  z \leq b$

Then $f(a) = m$ is the  minimum of the function

$f(z) =M>m \implies$ there exist some $\delta >0$ such that $f(x)>m+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ for all $x\in (z-\delta,z]$

Thus we have that $\begin{aligned}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx & = \underbrace{\int_{a}^{z-\delta}f(x)dx}_{\geq f(a)\cdot(z-\delta -a)} +\underbrace{\int_{z-\delta}^{z}f(x)dx}_{\geq (f(a) + \epsilon)\cdot\delta>f(a)\cdot \delta}+\underbrace{\int_{z}^{b}f(x)dx}_{\geq f(a)\cdot(b-z)}>f(a)\cdot(b-a)\\  &\underbrace{\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx}_{f(c)} > f(a)\end{aligned}$

that is a contradiction. Then $c \neq a$

I hope it help you,
I think the other cases will be analogous

(for example, apply this reasoning to $-f$)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach. Assume that $$f(x) > K=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) \, dx$$ for all $x\in(a, b) $. This means that $g(x) =f(x) - K>0$ for all $x\in(a, b) $. Hence $$\int_{a} ^{b} g(x) \, dx>0$$ ie $$\int_{a} ^ {b} f(x) \, dx>K(b-a) $$ which is absurd.

Similarly one can show that $f(x) <K$ for all $x\in(a, b) $ can't hold. Thus by intermediate value theorem we must have $f(c) =K$ for some $c\in(a, b) $.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:
[image]

What is the area in blue?

$$\int\limits_a^b f(x)\ dx$$

What is the area in orange?

$$f(c) \cdot (b-a)$$

QED.